# how to translate from udev path to ACPI Device

Tags: linux-device-driver, device-tree, acpi

I have a PCI device as follows

> DEVPATH=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:0c.0/0000:04:00.0

```
% lspci -s 04:0
04:00.0 Non-VGA unclassified device:
```

This publishes multiple i2c buses. So am attempting to learn how to translate this to ACPI.

Investigation so far

```sh
% cat /sys/bus/pci/devices/0000\:00\:0c.0/firmware_node/path
\_SB_.PCI0.PEX3
```

So, I create the device within the scope of this device and address as shown by the last part of DEVPATH

```asl
     Scope (\_SB_.PCI0.PEX3)
     {
             Device (PD01)
             {
                 Name (_ADR, 0x00040000)
                     Device (CH00)
                     {
                         Name (_ADR, 00)
                         Name (_HID, "PRP0001")
                         Name (_STR, Unicode("MUX0"))
                         Name (_CRS, ResourceTemplate ()
                                 {
                                 I2cSerialBus (0x70, ControllerInitiated, 100000,
                                         AddressingMode7Bit, "\\_SB_.PCI0.PEX3.PD01.CH00", 0x00,
                                         ResourceConsumer,,)
                                 })
                         Name (_DSD, Package ()
                                 {
                                 ToUUID("daffd814-6eba-4d8c-8a91-bc9bbf4aa301"),
                                 Package () {
                                 Package (2) { "compatible", "nxp,pca9548" },
                                 }
                                 })
                     }
            }
        }
```

I then compile this with iASL and add the table dynamically using the [Loading SSDT with configfs](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/admin-guide/acpi/ssdt-overlays.html).

When I monitor this using the `udevadm monitor` I see that the ACPI device are created, but the PCA9548 is not loaded.

```sh
% cat /sys/bus/acpi/devices/PRP0001\:03/path
\_SB_.PCI0.PEX3.OCOR.CH03
```

Should the kernel driver used for the FPGA do any special handling to allow ACPI to permit the devices below it be discovered?

The FPGA driver is auto-loaded as part of PCI enumeration.

Is there any error in how I have nested the Device definition?

Comment: It appears that the the API "Device Property" does not yet work for all devices in Debian-Stretch (Kernel: 4.9.189) might not support this fully yet.

I see this which adds the capability for this only in recent comit. https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/?id=753aa3694382c5d967dcb427ae0c3ee199bd21aa

Comment: `iasl` should give you a warning that *_HID* and *_ADR* can't coexists. You put `Device (CH0)` to a wrong scope. I highly recommend to use latest release of ACPICA tools. You should have something like `Device (I2C0) { Name (_ADR, ...) ... Device (MUX) { Name (_HID, "PRP0001") ... Device (CH0) { ... }) ... }) ... })`